# PHP - TCPDF not displaying page and table

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

Somethings wrong with my syntax, the page and the table is not displaying. I dont know for sure. Can anyone help me? Tnx

Ive been this script even here in stackoverflow. Ive tested the tcpdf examples and they are working. So i made sample project placed this one in a single page. WHen I try to run it. Nothing is displaying.

Please help.

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
    //require_once('../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8',       false);

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);


    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

    // Add a page

    $pdf->AddPage("L");

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT fname,mname,lname FROM emp_tbl");


    $tbl_header = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';
    $tbl_footer = '</table>';
    $tbl = '';

    $tbl_header = '<table id="gallerytab" width="600" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1"   border="0">
    <tr>
    <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Employee Name</font></th>

    </tr>';

    $tbl_footer = '</table>';
    $tbl = '';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
$tbl .= '
<tr>
    <td>'.$row['fname'].''.$row['mname'].''.$row['lname'].'</td>
</tr>
        ';
   }
     // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

    ?>
```

Comment: Just wondering why your language file is commented out and also why you declare the `$tbl_header` and footer twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php file is not quite done. How did you want your PDF output (ex. to a file, inline to browser, etc)? Either way add something such as:

```
return $pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
```

- I: inline
- D: download in browser
- F: save file to server
- S: output as php string

And that should do it.

Comment: well i would like to display the results as a pdf in the browser... where do I place this one, if you dont mind me asking for assurance.. tnx alot

Comment: tnx mate, the output is great. You help me alot!